# elisp how to apply a lambda to a list?

Tags: list, lambda, lisp, elisp, apply

What I'm trying to do seems simple enough, and whatever's wrong must be a really dumb mistake, since I couldn't find other people getting the same error. I just want to apply a lambda to a list - the lambda here isn't what I actually want to do, but it gives the same error.

```
(apply
(lambda (arg)
  (+ 5 arg)
)
(list 2 3 4)
)
```

When I try to run this, it tells me that I'm passing the lambda an invalid number of arguments. Do you have any advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`apply` calls the function *once*, passing it the list you've given as the arguments.  I think you instead want to use `mapcar`:

```
M-: (mapcar (lambda (arg) (+ 5 arg)) (list 2 3 4)) RET
```

will return the list `(7 8 9)`.

Answer (score 4):

Just to make the problem a bit clearer:

This form

```
(apply
 (lambda (arg)
   (+ 5 arg))
 (list 2 3 4))
```

is basically similar to

```
(funcall
 (lambda (arg)
   (+ 5 arg))
 2
 3
 4)
```

In above we try to call a function with one parameter `arg` with three arguments.

Now if you want to pass more than one argument and receive it as a single list you would need a function with a `&rest` parameter:

```
(lambda (&rest args) ...)
```

You say

> I just want to apply a lambda

This is not what you want. You want to *map the function over a list*. Which means calling the function for each element of the list and returning a new list with the results. This operation is called in Lisp *mapping*. See the answer by Stefan for an example.

*Applying a function* to a list would be: call the function with the arguments taken from the list.